# Qt5 cross-compilation with Texas Instruments DVSDK - undefined reference errors

Tags: c++, qt5, cross-compiling, linkage, texas-instruments

I am trying to compile Qt for Embedded Linux system with TI DVSDK.
http://www.ti.com/tool/linuxdvsdk-dm37x

So far everything went ok, I was able to build the root filesystem via buildroot with all the required libraries (I believe), Qt configure went fine, then I do "make".

Unfortunately in the end of compilation there are always linker errors:

```
.obj/release-shared/qguivariantanimation.o: In function `global constructors keyed to qguivariantanimation.cpp':
qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)'
qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)'
qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)'
qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)'
qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)'
.obj/release-shared/qguivariantanimation.o:qguivariantanimation.cpp:(.text+0xb0): more undefined references to `QVariantAnimation::registerInterpolator(QVariant (*)(void const*, void const*, float), int)' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.1.1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/alexey/tenzor/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/qtbase/src/gui'
make[2]: *** [sub-gui-make_first] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/alexey/tenzor/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/qtbase/src'
make[1]: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/alexey/tenzor/qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1/qtbase'
make: *** [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

My `configure` line is:

```
./configure -prefix /usr/local/qt5 -release -make libs -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-ti-g++ -opengl es2 -confirm-license -opensource -icu -no-xcb -no-pch -no-fontconfig -no-c++11 -verbose
```

It's not clear for me what could cause this. Please help, any advise is appreciated :)

Comment: TI doesn't do a very good job updating SDKs, pretty much whatever gcc version is current when the part is released is what you get :(

Comment: Pretty much you're going to need to look at the command that failed (about 10 lines of linker arguments, I suspect), run `nm` on each library passed in to see if any of them contains the missing function, then change the library order so that the library providing the function appears in the list after the object that requires it.